# Fallback for CSS attributes without unit

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, w3c

Consider a scenario where CSS attribute is missing the unit (px, em, pt, %):

```
<body>
    <div 
        style=  "width:170;
                border:1 dotted PaleGreen;
                background-color:MistyRose">
        The quick brown
    </div>
</body>
```

**Questions:**

1. Why would it fallback to px? Is pixel always a preferred unit? Is there any rule defined in W3C working draft or recommendation?
2. Is there a rule which makes it mandatory for a UA to fallback to a preferred unit?
3. Given the above example, which of the following is a correct behavior:

   - Internet Explorer: In Quirks mode (IE6,5,4..) width and border-width used to fallback to px. Since IE7 (till present, IE10RP) it ignores the whole rule if unit is missing. Therefore both rules were ignored.
   - Firefox 13: In the above example width fallback to px, but border-width was ignored.
   - Chrome 19, Opera 12, Safari 5.1.2: Both width and border-width fallback to px.

Note: On Microsoft-Connect, they said:

> The issue you are reporting is by design. IE10 in standards mode ignores a width or height without a unit in compliance with the CSS standards. *The unit is not optional.*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't see a doctype declaration in your HTML, so I can only assume your test page is being rendered in quirks mode.

1. > Why would it fallback to px? Is pixel always a preferred unit? Is there any rule defined in W3C working draft or recommendation?

   It will only fall back to `px` in quirks mode (and I believe only for certain properties). And yes, `px` is the preferred fallback unit. This harks back to the legacy HTML `width` and `height` attributes which accepted pixel lengths as unitless numbers.
2. > Is there a rule which makes it mandatory for a UA to fallback to a preferred unit?

   No, hence the inconsistent behavior you observe. In standards mode, though, a UA needs to ignore length values without units; the unit is not optional, as mentioned in Microsoft Connect which you quote.

   [In CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units), all non-zero length values must have units.
3. > Given the above example, which of the following is a correct behavior:
   >
   > - Internet Explorer: In Quirks mode (IE6,5,4..) width and border-width used to fallback to px. Since IE7 (till present, IE10RP) it ignores the whole rule if unit is missing. Therefore both rules were ignored.
   > - Firefox 13: In the above example width fallback to px, but border-width was ignored.
   > - Chrome 19, Opera 12, Safari 5.1.2: Both width and border-width fallback to px.

   Again, based on the assumption that your page is in quirks mode, I can only say that while the specifications make a mention of quirky behavior, the specific details of such quirky behavior aren't defined in the specifications (for both obvious and not-so-obvious reasons).

   I'm guessing Microsoft changed the quirks-mode behavior in IE7+ to reflect standards behavior for unitless values, as quirks mode exists in **all browsers** (except IE < 6) and is triggered with the same improper doctype or lack of a doctype. The behavior in standards mode has not changed, though, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: This is a correct answer. When I used the HTML5's doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`, all the aforementioned browsers ignore the width and border. I never knew that other browsers also behave differently in quirks mode. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. `px` is the most common unit used, so generally browsers use their "common sense" and use `px` as it is the most used unit in web designs if no unit is specified.
2. No there is no such rule. Browsers just use the most used unit in designs.
3. The ideal behaviour should be to use `px` and move on without ignoring other styles, but there is no such rule so when you see different browsers different things they are actually implementing there own logic to counter such errors there is no one rule to follow in such scenarios. It depends on the browser on what it does.

You should never rely on the browser to correct your mistake. Always rely on yourself for better *cross browser compatibility*

Comment: The issue was due to the lack of doctype.

Comment: @Ashwin Singh, is point number 1 correct?