# Output sibling divs next to each other using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, position

I'm trying to create the thumbs next to each other but it's not working. It appears to be outputting them on top of each other. I want them to be 5px apart.

--- I need positioning to be absolute. I need that so that after I get them all next to each other, I want the one that's clicked to grow, and all the ones to the left should disappear to the left, all those right should go right. Absolute Positioning is needed so that I can control that.

HTML

```
<div class="portItem">
    <div class="itemContent-wrap">
        <div class="itemContent">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="thumbWrap">
                    <div class="thumb"></div>
                    <div class="thumb"></div>
                    <div class="thumb"></div>
                    <div class="thumb"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.thumb {
  height: 200px;
  width: 450px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #D0E182;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.portItem').each(function() {
        $('.thumb', this).each(function(i) {
              $('.thumb').css('left',40*i);
         }).appendTo('.body');
     });
});
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/nTHDk/11/

Solution!: http://jsfiddle.net/nTHDk/14/

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Remove positioning and then `float: left;` ?

Comment: I need positioning to be absolute. I need that so that after I get them all next to each other, I want the one that's clicked to grow, and all the ones to the left should disappear to the left, all those right should go right. Absolute Positioning is needed so that I can control that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.thumb').css('left',40*i);` should be `$(this).css('left',40*i);`. You were selecting all `.thumb` elements in the DOM but you've already selected the correct one at that point.

http://jsfiddle.net/nTHDk/8/

Comment: Still only outputs one rectangle (even in the fiddle you've attached). Thanks

Comment: @yahyanono Funny, someone added the fiddle to my answer. The rectangles are correctly positioned, its just that they are only staggered by `40px` but they're `450px` wide so they overlay a lot. Check-out this demo where I made your divs narrower: http://jsfiddle.net/nTHDk/8/

Comment: also mention `px`.. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green What's that?

Comment: Yeah sorry it was me first time. I did it based on @yahyanono jsfiddle. Also as MR_Green said, its good to use correct units: css('left', 40*i + 'px')

Comment: @Mr_Green Nope :). Check the jQuery documentation, any integer value is evaluated as a pixel amount.

Comment: yureka moment! (regarding your comment about how they were only staggered by 40px - changed it to 460*i). thank you!

Comment: yes using `px` is not necessary if [it is a number but not string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13762031/1577396).

Answer (score 2):

you have a lot of typos in your code:

see this [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/nTHDk/4/)

1. you didn't add Jquery to your fiddle.
2. in the fiddle you don't need to write the `document.ready`
3. for each selection use `$(this).css('left',40*i +"px");` //notice *this* and *px*
4. you'r box sizes were too big to notice the movement, I reduced them.
5. I removed the `appendTo`, the elements are already located in your DOM (did you wish to move them?)
6. if you wish to use the `appenedTo` function, fix the selector to `$('body')`

Comment: `px` isn't necessary as jQuery interprets integers as pixel values.

Comment: 1) true, my bad
2) cool, thanks
3) don't think the px made a difference
4) i need them to be that size though
5) no that's fine
6)can't put the $ right after appendTo... I don't think that's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change `position:absolute` to `position:relative` and `$('thumb').css('left', 40*i)` to `$(this).css('left',40*i);`

The change to JavaScript isn't necessary, but they way you are doing it is redundant.  The change to CSS will get your spacing.  When you use `position:absolute` they are all positioned on top of each other.

Comment: I need positioning to be absolute. I need that so that after I get them all next to each other, I want the one that's clicked to grow, and all the ones to the left should disappear to the left, all those right should go right. Absolute Positioning is needed so that I can control that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add jQuery to your fiddle, and you are actually moving all the .thumb elements in the inner each loop, you have to use $(this), like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.portItem').each(function() {
        $(this).find('.thumb').each(function(i) {
              $(this).css('left',50*i);
         }).appendTo('.body');
     });
});
```

This is the new [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nTHDk/10/)