# javascript - manipulate parent div through by child values

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child, dom-manipulation

*Hello everybody i am trying to get along with javascript by manipulating the parent div with the height value of the child div.*

**How does it look like till now?**

*This is my javascript code that gives me the height of the child div:*

```
onload=function() {
  var divh = parseInt(document.getElementById('lookfor').offsetHeight);
  b = parseInt("70");
  c = divh + b;

  //This shall insert the value to the parent div
  document.all.air.style.height = "c";
}
```

*And this is the structure of the html:*

```
<div id="air">
   <div id="lookfor"></div>
</div>
```

**The problem is that there is no value inserted to the parent div by my code - how can i do this?**

*The reason why i am doing this and do not just adjust the problem by css is that the child's position is absolute. So i can't handle the parents size by min-height or something like this.*

Comment: It should be `c` not `"c"` ... `"c"` is read as a string and not a variable.

Comment: It still happens nothing when i change it to c.

Comment: It needs to be `c + "px"`.  If there is no `"px"` appended to it, than it's just a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.all.air.style.height = (divh + 70) + "px";
```

Comment: That did it. Was it just because of the missing px? The script did not showed a broken css rule

Comment: Units are required for all size attributes, unless you're using quirks mode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274904/fallback-for-css-attributes-without-unit

Comment: Okay i took a look on Firefox and it says that document.all is undefined

Comment: Just replace with document.getElementById('air')

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.all.air.style.height = c + "px";
```