# Firefox element with width=n doesn't show

Tags: javascript, css, svg, cross-browser, d3.js

I have a very simple code, that works on Chrome, but not on firefox:

**JS**

```
//Creating the svg element
svgContainer= d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")

//fill it with blue and set it's width to 0
svgContainer
    .style("background-color","blue")
    .style("width",0);

//change the size again
svgContainer
    .style("width",200)
```

**HTML**

```
<body>        
</body>
```

In chrome, the rectangle draws, but not on firefox. Seems like you can't change the value of the style element a second time. Strange, isn't it ?

Here's a JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/cUmXu/2/

EDIT: Actually, you can change the value, but not if the first value you have given to the width is 0. This is even though strange.

SECOND EDIT: Seems that when using

```
svgContainer
    .style("width","200px")
```

it works. If someone knows why, please share.

Comment: This is simply because of how different browsers interpret ambiguous size specifications.

Comment: For size styling 0 is ok without units; all other numbers need unit because px is not the only one possible unit

Comment: units are mandatory with CSS lengths except for the special value 0. This is a Chrome bug as it's not following the CSS 2.1 specification i.e. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your code

```
svgContainer
    .style("width",200)
```

you created the following element (Chrome):

```
<svg style="background-color: blue; width: 200px;"></svg>
```

At Firefox we got just

```
<svg style="background-color: blue; width: 0px;">
```

Chrome is just more forgiving for some mistakes then Firefox. `width` can have different units like %, em, pt, px... so you have to provide unit with number greater then 0. But 0 without unit is allowed because 0em is the same as 0px.

From [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/):

*Lengths refer to distance measurements and are denoted by  in the property definitions. A length is a dimension. However, for zero lengths the unit identifier is optional (i.e. can be syntactically represented as the  ‘0’).*

So, with

```
svgContainer
    .style("width", "200px")
```

we get also at Firefox proper width:

```
<svg style="background-color: blue; width: 200px;">
```

See also [Fallback for CSS attributes without unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274904/fallback-for-css-attributes-without-unit)