# setting element width without "px"

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I had no problems writing code like below before:

```
d3element.style("width", width)
```

However, a few minutes ago, it suddenly stopped working even though I did not change the any JavaScript, in both Chrome and Firefox. I had to add `"px"` manually in order for it to work:

```
d3element.style("width", width + "px")
```

What could be a possible reason for this? Was it a browser update?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/56dg85hv/3/) is the JSFiddle.

Comment: add `%` in place of `px`

Comment: @Amitsingh I am aware of the difference between `px` and `%`. `px` is absolute unit and `%` is percentage unit.

Comment: @Amit singh are you crazy? Thats something completely different!

Comment: @paradite Are you certain that the value of `width` hadn't changed?

Comment: Browser elements have always required a unit for size/location. Most likely the variable `width` had a unit already.

Comment: @Curt please see my update

Comment: @jaunt please see my update

Comment: If you add "px" to your second js line it breaks the first as well :)

Comment: @Sander I don't get what you mean, in my case they are independent. See http://jsfiddle.net/56dg85hv/3/

Comment: @LGSon the answer to that question did not solve my issue. But one the comment did. It turns out that I added `<!DOCTYPE html>` which causes the first line to not work.

Comment: @LGSon the question you posted was about the statically declaring but my question is for dynamic setting, hence the answers in the previous question failed to address the fact that the presence of `<!DOCTYPE html>` controls the behavior of JavaScript.

Comment: @LGSon yes they are, but is question not specifically due to introducing the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag. But if you really insist on the duplicate, please raise another flag then.

Comment: I guess I made myself unclear, it doesn't matter if you set the width statically or dynamically, the unit is not optional. If one still do then, based on whether one used a doc type or not, the behavior will differ between the browsers as they fallback differently, so the "possible duplicate" post describe both the reason this happened to you, what caused it and how to solve it, or leave it as is, based on what outcome you want.

Comment: @LGSon marked as duplicate as you wished.

Comment: @paradite I upvoted your question as it is a good one, I suggested the "duplicate" as it has both good answers and comments ... as I see a win-win situation for you, me and the next user reading this ... there are many good questions with only one answer

Answer (score 5):

It turned out that it was due to the addition of `<!DOCTYPE html>` into my HTML file. I did not know it could cause such as huge difference.

The answer was in the comment of this question:
[Fallback for CSS attributes without unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274904/fallback-for-css-attributes-without-unit)

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior, you have to include the units or it won't work consistently.

From official d3 API documentation for selection.style :

> Note that CSS styles typically have associated units. For example, "3px" is a valid stroke-width property value, while 3 is not. Although some browsers implicitly assign the "px" (pixel) unit to numeric values, not all browsers do: IE, for example, throws an “invalid arguments” error and stops executing!

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#style

Note that this has mostly to do with CSS rules instead of d3 peculiarities.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include a unit after your number

`Value Error : width only 0 can be a length. You must put a unit after your number : 50`

Take a look at https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input and input

```
.width {
    width: 50;
}
```