# How do I move this three line navigation bar in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble moving this three-line navigation bar to the top while making sure the hover effect works. The `#MenIcon` is where I managed to move it to the top. However, when I hovered my mouse over the three line navigation bar, it didn't do the animation I had created when the three line navigation bar was not exactly at the top.

```
#MenuIcon{
    height: 25px;
    width: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 60; /*I want this to be 5. But when I do this, the hover effect doesn't work*/
    right: 50;
}

#MenuIcon:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

#MenuLine{
    height: 4px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: white; /* #181818 */
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transition: all .3s;
}

#MenuIcon:hover #MenuLine{
    width: 40px;
}

#MenuLine::before{
    content: '';
    height: 4px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    transition: all .3s;
}

#MenuIcon:hover #MenuLine::before{
    width: 50px;
}

#MenuLine::after{
    content: '';
    height: 4px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -10px;
    transition: all .3s;
}

#MenuIcon:hover #MenuLine::after{
    width: 50px;
}
```

Edit: Here's the HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link href="Resources/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Boogaloo" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="Resources/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Resources/JQUERY%20Main.js"></script>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fullscreen-bg">
            <video loop muted autoplay poster="Images/Videos/home.mp4" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
                <source src="Images/Videos/home.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div id="MenuIcon">
            <div id="MenuLine"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML as well?

Comment: "top: 60;" is invalid.  Needs a unit (px, em, vh, something)

Comment: on #MenuIcon (assuming that's the parent el) have you tried using transform?

Comment: Actually, @DanielBeck, that is not invalid. It will vary between browsers though. Not good style. But still works;

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade Yes, omitting units for non-zero lengths really is [invalid](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units), and really [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274904/fallback-for-css-attributes-without-unit) in any browser more recent than IE6: https://jsfiddle.net/8yh7d4Lx/.

Comment: @DanielBeck I have now added "px" as the units and I changed the top value back to 10, but the hover effect still doesn't work.

Comment: @JoeFrank You still need to supply the HTML so we can reproduce the problem. Without that the best we can do is guess at the solution. [mcve]

Comment: @DanielBeck I have posted the HTML.

Comment: @pavger I have posted the HTML.

Comment: @joe-frank in your css comment, you said 'I want this to be 5'. What did you mean by that? That you want the `#MenuIcon` to be `5px` from the top?

Comment: @joe-frank I just posted my answer. Let me know if that solved it for you. If not, then I think it's a `z-index` issue which I can quickly solve and edit/update my answer to fix that for you.

Comment: @pavger Yes, I want the `#MenuIcon` to be `5px` from the top. I copied the code you posted and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @joe-frank It doesn't work because it's not positioned correctly or it doesn't work because you can't click on it?

Comment: @pavger It doesn't work because when I change the value to '5px' which is the spot I want it in, the hover effect doesn't work. Nothing happens.

Comment: @joe-frank so you used the code in my answer? Then the top should be 35px not 5px. If you change the code to match my answer it should work. Although this could be a z-index issue. I'll update my answer, then try it out. Sorry for the back and forth, just trying to nail down what's going on.

Comment: @pavger It works! The z-index issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are having `z-index` issues or not since the files are linking to your local files in your code snippet but here is what I think would help it out. I changed the size of `#MenuIcon` to cover all of `#MenuLine` so that now it's always hovering over it and it's in the position that I think you wanted it in. Then change the `z-index` on the `#MenuIcon` and `.fullscreen-bg`. That way `#MenuIcon` will always be on top of `.fullscreen-bg`.

```
#MenuIcon{
    height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 35px;
    right: 26px;
    z-index: 10;
}

#MenuLine{
    height: 4px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: white; /* #181818 */
    position: relative;
    top: 18px;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.fullscreen-bg {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```