# (CSS in JS) Is there any difference between "18px" vs 18 when specifying sizes

Tags: javascript, css, css-in-js

I've worked as React Native dev for a while, and am kinda new to web dev.
Recently came across codebase where people specify sizes in different formats mixed together.

(From what I've read so far, from the accessibility standpoint it's often best to specify font sizes / margins with `rem` or `em`, and yet there's a lot of people discussing when to use which.)

But let's just say you want to specify sizes in pixels.
There are just 2 ways you can do in "CSS in JS".

With string

```
  fontSize: "15px",
  lineHeight: "22.5px",
  marginTop: "20px",
```

With number

```
  fontSize: 15,
  lineHeight: 22.5,
  marginTop: 20,
```

Is there any difference between the 2? Would love to know if there's any pros and cons.
Thanks!

Comment: has been discussed before, just go [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11274904/8134014)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do exactly the same, but the 2nd is shorter, then I would recommend the 2nd.

Comment: For font size specifically I'd specify "px" because in my mind the default unit for font sizes is "pt" even though that's not how the library works. Programming is not just for compilers, it's also for humans to read (especially myself several months later)